# What's the word that sounds like “convolution” in this recording?

Tags: meaning

Here's what I think about what [this recording](http://cl.ly/9lX1) says:

> So they thought this behavior, this convolution and stuff, is a reaction against the witch.

I can't get the word that sounds vaguely like convolution to me.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I hear:

> And so they saw this behaviour, these [convulsions](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/convulsion), this stuff… as a reaction against the witch, in other words, the idea was …

Comment: Convulsions is what I hear too.